# Make correspond rotation to preview

Tags: keyframes, axis

I'm trying to rotate a star (made of multiples spheres) but my star is downsized before restored to normal size ,causing me troubles.
Here is the rotation I performed (and looks fine in preview)
[image]

And here is the result when adding the keyframe

[image]

I'm guessing Blender resolves the rotation as simplement straigth forwards movements and circular ones. How to make this ?

Comment: maybe try Euler rotation instead of Quaternion?

Comment: Quaternion rotation in the video capture is already an unsucesfull attempt. I've rollbacked  to Euler rotation since (default) since

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty in the center of the star, parent all spheres to the empty and animate the rotation of the empty.

Comment: it works, except it has broke a my previous keyframes as they've been set without this object addition.